# How to download an lightning application as pdf?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, pdf, aura

I have a lightning component embedded in a lightning application. 
How can we download the data present in the lightning component as soon as the component is rendered in the application or any button click on the application?

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7, this is a requirement to complete at my end

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria, currently I have not found any solution or workaround for this.